# Treating a subclass differently / avoiding code-duplication

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering how to avoid code-duplication in a scenario as given below.

(There's this question:
[How do I check if an object's type is a particular subclass in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307765/what-is-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-objects-type-is-a-particular-subclass)

The answer there is that it's not possible and even with dynamic casts member access wouldn't be possible, I guess.)

So I'm wondering how you avoid having almost the same code in different methods, where just one method would have a few additional operations.

```
class Basic {
    ...
}

class Advanced : public Basic {
    ...
}


AnotherClass::lengthy_method(Basic *basic) {
    // do a lot of processing, access members of basic

    if (*basic is actually of class Advanced)
        // do one or a few specific things with members of Advanced

    // more processing just using Basic

    if (*basic is actually of class Advanced)
        // do one or a few specific things with members of Advanced

    // more processing just using Basic
}
```

Also from a design perspective `AnotherClass::lengthy_method` wouldn't want to be defined in `Basic` or `Advanced` since it's not really belonging to either of them. It's just operating on their kind.

I'm curious what the language experts know and I hope there's a nice solution, maybe at least through some functionality from C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` can be used here, as long as the `Advanced` members you want to access are declared as `public`, or `AnotherClass` is declared as a `friend` of `Advanced`:

```
AnotherClass::lengthy_method(Basic *basic) {
    // do a lot of processing, access members of basic

    Advanced *adv = dynamic_cast<Advanced*>(basic);
    if (adv != NULL) {
        // use adv as needed...
    }

    // more processing just using Basic

    if (adv != NULL) {
        // use adv as needed...
    }

    // more processing just using Basic
}
```

Another option is to use polymorphism instead of RTTI.  Expose some additional virtual methods in `Basic` that do nothing, and then have `Advanced` override them:

```
class Basic {
    ...
    virtual void doSomething1() {}
    virtual void doSomething2() {}
}

class Advanced : public Basic {
    ...
    virtual void doSomething1();
    virtual void doSomething2();
}

void Advanced::doSomething1() {
    ...
}

void Advanced::doSomething2() {
    ...
}    

AnotherClass::lengthy_method(Basic *basic) {
    // do a lot of processing, access members of basic

    // do one or a few specific things with members of Advanced
    basic->doSomething1();

    // more processing just using Basic

    // do one or a few specific things with members of Advanced
    basic->doSomething2();

    // more processing just using Basic
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very good to know that member access of `Advanced` is actually possible.

Comment: Why did you think it was not possible?

Comment: To me it is surprising that the compiler allows access to a member that might not exist.

Comment: It won't. You cannot `dynamic_cast` an object pointer to another *unrelated* type. If the cast succeeds, you have a valid pointer and can access members of the type you casted to. If the cast fails, you have a NULL pointer and cannot access the failed type's members.