# How to inherit and display inherited class object list as a part of other object

Tags: public

I have 3 classes (*Air*, *Ocean* and *Ground*) representing 3 modes of transportation:

**Air:**

```
Class Air
{

  public int ID;
  public datetime Start;
  public datetime End;

  public string FlightNo;

}
```

**Ground:**

```
Class Ground
{

  public int ID;
  public datetime Start;
  public datetime End;

  public string VehicleNo;
  public string DriverName;
  public string DriverMobile;

}
```

**Ocean:**

```
Class Ocean
{

  public int ID;
  public datetime Start;
  public datetime End;

  public string VessalName;
  public string FTZNo;

}
```

I have an object named *Job*. *Transportation* is a part of *Job*. *Job* can have multiple `Transportation(Air, Ocean, Ground)`

How to assign *Transportation* list in *Job* class?

Comment: please post a valid code and specify the programming language in question tag

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear.In my understanding your question is how to assign a Transportation list to Job object? Right? I assumed Job class has a member of type

```
List<Tranportation> transList;
```

And all the Air,Water and Ground are subclass of Transportation. so you can assign the list with a setter method. say

```
void setTransportationList(List<Transportation> x){
    this.transList=x;
}
```

*EDIT*

Lets say you have to print the details of the traspotations used in the Job object

```
Class Job{
     public List<Transportation> trainsList;


     public void setTransportationList(List<Transportation> x){
        this.transList=x;
     }
     void printTransportationDetails(){
         Iterator itr = this.transList.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext()) {
         Transportation element = itr.next();
         element.printDetails();
         }
     }
}
```

Now your Transportation subclass should have a printDetails() member function.

Comment: but some time job may have 3 types of transportation same time. Is it i want to create 3 diffrent proprty list in job?

Comment: You can have a List of Transportation objects with the type List<Transportation>. So that you can access the multiple entries in the list as you like. Does this answer your question??

Comment: but Air have only flight no , ground have 3 extra proeprty , ocean have 2 extra proprty

Comment: now this problem can be solved with the solution from the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307765/what-is-a-good-way-to-check-if-an-objects-type-is-a-particular-subclass    Does this solves your problem??

Comment: how will be my job class  properties ?

Comment: note the edit. If this answers your question accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: But gman i need to print flight no with flight no label and Vehicle no with vehicle no label

Comment: You can always do so by having different definitions for printDetails() in Air, Ocean and Ground classes.

Comment: class job { List<Air> m_objAirlList; List<Ground> m_objGroundList; List<Oean> m_objOceanList; }

Comment: yeah, Thats one one solution.