# Casting a pointer toc the base class to a pointer to subclass - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, casting, dynamic-memory-allocation

This post is a working example for this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510322/objects-type-in-a-has-a-relationship-c/30511011?noredirect=1#comment49100316_30511011). However, there are some points that confuse me. That is why I am posting it as another question.

Basically, the problem is how to cast a base class to its subclasses. People have suggested using dynamic memory and `new`ing a fresh instance of the subclass.

I cam up with the following solution, and now wonder how this works. I create an object of the base class (Employee). Set its Id. Then I cast its pointer to a pointer of the subclass and set more members.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
 public:
  int getId() { return id;}
   void setId( int id) {this->id = id;}
 protected:
  int id;

};

class PartTimeEmployee : public Employee {

};

class FullTimeEmployee : public Employee {
 public:
  int getGrade() {return grade;}
  void setGrade(int grade) {this->grade = grade;}
 private:
  int grade;
};

class Organization {
 public:    
  void addEmployee(Employee* e) { empList.push_back(e); }
  Employee* getEmployee(int id) { 
      for (std::list<Employee*>::iterator it=empList.begin(); it!=empList.end(); ++it) {
          if((*it)->getId() == id) {return (*it);}
      }
      return NULL; 
  }
 private:
  std::list<Employee*> empList;
};

int main()
{
  Employee e1;
  e1.setId(5);

  FullTimeEmployee *pFt1 = (FullTimeEmployee*) &e1; 
  pFt1->setGrade(1);                

  Organization org1;
  org1.addEmployee(pFt1);
  FullTimeEmployee* pFt2 = (FullTimeEmployee*) org1.getEmployee(5);
  cout << pFt2->getId() << endl;
  cout << pFt2->getGrade() << endl;
}
```

Why does it work? I see it as follows:

Employee: |--id--|...
FullTimeEmployee: |--id--|--grade--|...

**1- Is this what happens in the background?** When I cast to the FullTimeemployee, C++ copies all pre-existing members of the Employee class plus giving you more space based on the size of the new type.

**2- Is it safe to use this approach?** Should I prefer dynamic memory allocation, e.g. `FullTimeEmployee *pFT1 = new FullTimeEmployee();` over this? If yes why? why can't I just go with pointer casting?

**UPDATE:** What makes this example different from casting to `void*`? You just play with memory addresses. What can go wrong as long as you know how much memory you need?

Comment: "Why does it work" - it doesn't. You were only fooled into believing it did. An `Employee` is not a `FullTimeEmployee`. The moment you claimed it was   (third line of `main()`) the train left the track and hurtled into the abyss.

Comment: @WhozCraig: How is it different from casting to void*?, what is wrong with it if you know how much memory your new type would occupy?

Comment: You're violating a number of rules in the language, and in so doing invoking undefined behavior. I honestly can't put it any simpler than that. Cast to `void*` all you want, that *still* doesn't make an `Employee` a `FullTimeEmployee`

Answer (score 3):

It only *seems* to work, because `e1`  is *not* an instance of any of the child classes, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To make it work, you need to use dynamic memory allocations:

```
Emplyoee *e1 = new FullTimeEmployee;
```

Now it works with the casting, because `e1` actually points to a `FullTimeEmployee` object.

But you should really use `static_cast`, like

```
FullTimeEmployee *pFt1 = static_cast<FullTimeEmployee*>(e1);
pFt1->setGrade(1);
```

Or just

```
static_cast<FullTimeEmployee*>(e1)->setGrade(1);
```

Also you should read about [**downcasting**](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php#Downcasting), which is what you are doing.

Comment: `Employee* pFt1 = new FullTimeEmployee();
  pFt1->setGrade(1); `   In function 'int main()':
49:9: error: 'class Employee' has no member named 'setGrade'

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism Read my *whole* answer please.

Comment: Alright. I got the new edit now. But, that's exactly what I asked. So, you think I must go for the dynamic memory approach. There is no way to do this on the stack. right? Then I will need a virtual destructor and everything. right?

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism The only way to do it on the stack is if you declare `e1` to *be* an `FullTimeEmployee` object instance. And yes virtual destructor would be a good idea.

Comment: I am still having a problem. At the end of they day, they are all addresses. What prevents you from doing what I did? I mean it is like saying never cast to void*, because you don't know the size of the memory it points to.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism But if you do like you do in the question, the variable `e1` is an instance of `Employee`, and have only the `id` member. When you write to the `grade` field using the `FullTimeEmployee` pointer, where do you write then? The object `e1` doesn't *have* a `grade` member.

Comment: I don't do that. I say now this address points to an object which needs more memory and includes a grade member, by: `FullTimeEmployee *pFt1 = (FullTimeEmployee*) &e1; `