# Does having to "ask which exact type an object has" always indicate bad design?

Tags: c++, casting, derived-class

At several places here in SO, it is claimed that having to know the exact type of an object and make a decision based on that (in an `if-then-else` manner) points to a design flaw, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307765/how-do-i-check-if-an-objects-type-is-a-particular-subclass-in-c).

I am wondering if this is always the case. In a current small educational project (which I'm using to learn C++) I want to implement arithmetic structures, i.e. terms (such as `(3+4)*x-5`) and equations (`x=3*y+z`). Now, from a structural point of view, equations are very similar to terms (particularly they can all be parsed using the [Shaunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_detail)), so I created a base class `math_struct` that both `equation` and `term` derive from:

```
class math_struct;
class term : public math_struct {...};
class equation : public math_struct {
    void resolve_to(std::string subTerm);
    ...
};
```

`equation` has a method `resolve_to` that term does not have (since an equation can be resolved to a variable, which a term cannot), but other than that they are equal.

Now I have a method to parse a `math_struct` from a string:

```
static std::unique_ptr<math_struct> parse_math_struct(std::string formula);
```

The resulting `math_struct` can either be a term or an equation, depending on what the input string looks like. To know which it is, I have to do a `typeid` check and perform a cast to use, if available, the `resolve_to` member function.

Is this a design flaw – and how could I improve it?

Comment: Is `math_struct` an empty class?

Comment: `resolve_to(std::string)` doesn't return anything?

Comment: `math_struct` is not empty, it provides common functionality such as `to_string()`. `resolve_to` does not return anything, but restructures the equation such that some variable is on one side and the rest on the other.

E.g., 3*x+4 = 0 ==> resolve_to("x") ==> x = -4/3

Comment: Show some [MCVE]. It is not always a design flow, but it could be one

Comment: A think that a `dynamic_cast` could be enough here.

Comment: Even though this example is somewhat incomplete, the upcasting here definitely seems to be a design flow. Either base class lacks the necessary methods or downcasting is performed unreasonably. So you can either add all the required methods into the base class or make `parse_math_struct` behave like a dispatcher, rather than factory, that is return `void` but accept two callbacks to be invoked when `term` or `equation` object is constructed.

Comment: The types have nothing in common beyond being parseable with the same algorithm. I would keep the classes unrelated and probably have the parser return a [`std::variant<term, equation>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Seems to me as if terms could well have a `resolve_to()` which is a NOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I would call it a "flaw", but I would say the design could be improved. One potential problem with checking the type to see if you can call `resolve_to` is that the check could break if, for some reason, you find the need for a third class derived from `math_struct`. (Someone with a mathematical background should be aware that being unable to think of a reason why does not mean there is no reason why.)

A more robust option is to add a virtual function to the base class, a simple Boolean that returns `true` iff you can call `resolve_to`.

An even better option might be to think about what do you do if the thing you're dealing with is *not* an equation.

> To know which it is, I have to do a `typeid` check and perform a cast to use, if available, the `resolve_to` member function.

What do you do if the `resolve_to` member function is not available? Why not have a virtual function on the base class that is overridden to do that thing for `term`s and overridden to call `resolve_to` for `equation`s? (Or that is `resolve_to` for `equation`s.)

There might be a situation where the best option is to "ask which exact type an object has", but I do not believe this is it. (I know there's an XML parser that relies on this technique; I have not analyzed that to see if it could be improved.)

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to write a generic `resolve_to`. You'll need a few different variants, for different types of equations. Yes, it's simple for a `linear_equation`. It's not too hard for a `quadratic_equation`. Third- and 4th-order polynomials can still be resolved, and that's it - provable.

Either way - the fact that you need a few `resolve_to` variants suggests that you want a few classes derived from `equation`, and all you need to know is whether an object IS-A `equation`. The exact type is pointless.

Comment: You're right in principle (although I'm not planning on implementing all these sophisticated `resolve_to`-methods ;-) ). I agree (also with the other comments) that only being "parseable" in the same way might not justify having the same base class. But still I find it hard to avoid double code in this context in a logical way without running into this "design flaw".