# Is there an inverse function for typeid in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17

Does C++17 provide a way to get the type from a typeid or is the factory pattern still the only methodology?

Comment: Do you mean the implementation defined `name()` of the `std::type_info`?

Comment: Remember that C++ is statically typed, so if you want to use a type in an expression you must know that type at compile-time. What would you use this for? An adequate answer is more likely if you give details on the use case.

Comment: I have a map in which I want to store a large variety of templated objects.  I have these classes inherit from an unparameterized base class, which allows me store them all in the same map.  When I retrieve an object, how can I determine its type?

Comment: @RFS You shouldn't really need to, because the base class should be a virtual interface that is used by the user of the map directly. If that is not the case, then you should probably not be using inheritance for polymorphism, but e.g. `std::variant`.

Comment: If you really need to do the way you are describing, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351845/finding-the-type-of-an-object-in-c or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307765/how-do-i-check-if-an-objects-type-is-a-particular-subclass-in-c should be a duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

`type_info` is a runtime value; its exact contents can only be determined via runtime execution. C++ is a statically typed language; at compile time, the type of *everything* must be known. As such, `type_info`-based reification (the ability to take a description of a thing and turn it into the thing itself) is not going to ever happen in C++.

C++ will likely get reflection and reification mechanisms in the future, but they will only be static mechanisms, not runtime mechanisms.