# Better event handling mechanism?

Tags: c++, events, event-handling

I am writing an event system for a GUI, where i have an `Event` base class and a couple of derived classes (e.g. `MouseDownEvent`, `MouseUpEvent`, ...etc).

and each GUI element registers a callback for each type of event that it's supposed/wants to handle.

here is what a "typical" callback looks like:

```cpp
bool OnMouseMove(const MouseMoveEvent& event);
```

and the event handling function looks something like this:

```cpp
bool OnEvent(Event& event)
{
    EventsDispatcher dispatcher(event);
    dispatcher.Dispatch<MouseMoveEvent>(/* std::bind the callback */);
    /* ... */
}
```

and `Dispatch` looks something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename Callback>
bool Dispatch(Callback&& callback)
{
    try
    {
        return callback(dynamic_cast<T&>(m_Event));
    }
    catch (const std::bad_cast&)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my problem is with the `dynamic_cast`ing in the `Dispatch` function, also according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307793/10777785) answer, if i have to do this kind of "workaround" then there is a design flow in the system, and i should reconsider it instead of trying to patch it!

is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: At the time when you emit the event you know the type of the even, so at the point of `bool OnEvent(Event& event)` you should know the type of the event. Registering the event listeners for a certain event, and finding the matching listeners for a certain event is indeed not an easy task, and results in such problems you have, but those should appear at a different point in the code.

Comment: I saw an implementation for event dispatching that, iirc, worked with using only minimal "hacks", and was as close as you can get to good code. But I  can't find it right now. I try to find it and to copy the relevant part as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To frame this generically, you have a bunch of type-erased objects (elements, events), and you need to dispatch to handlers for specific pairs of two types (e.g. `ElementA` and `MouseUpEvent`). This is a [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) problem, and there are two ways to deal with it in C++.

#### Double Dispatch Using The Visitor Pattern

This is the "classic" technique described in the [Design Patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book. Basically, the base event (node) has a virtual method that dispatches to a downcasted dispatch method in a element (visitor). The visitor methods are virtual methods which dispatch to the right element. You can read about it in the book, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), or a [billion](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/visitor.html) [online](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/2) [tutorials](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/visitor-design-pattern/). I can't make a better tutorial here, except to add that you can reduce the amount of boilerplate a lot by using variadic templates:

```cpp
// Visitor
template <typename... TNodes>
struct GenericVisitor;

template <typename TNode, typename... TNodes>
struct GenericVisitor<TNode, TNodes...> : public GenericVisitor<TNodes...> {
    virtual bool Visit(const TNode&) { return false; }
};
template <>
struct GenericVisitor<> {
    virtual ~GenericVisitor() = default;
};

// Node
template <typename TVisitor>
struct GenericBaseNode {
    virtual bool Accept(TVisitor& visitor) const = 0;
};
template <typename TNode, typename TVisitor>
struct GenericNode : public GenericBaseNode<TVisitor> {
    virtual bool Accept(TVisitor& visitor) const { return visitor.Visit(*static_cast<TNode*>(this)); }
};
```

After that, adding specifics for your setup can be done in just a few lines of code:

```cpp
struct MouseEvent;
struct KeyEvent;
using Element = GenericVisitor<MouseEvent, KeyEvent>;
using Event = GenericBaseNode<Element>;

struct MouseEvent : public GenericNode<MouseEvent, Element> { };
struct KeyEvent : public GenericNode<KeyEvent, Element> { };
struct ElementA : public Element {
    virtual bool Visit(const MouseEvent&) { return true; }
};
```

And to dispatch, just call the `Accept` method of an event:

```cpp
void DispatchEvent(Event& event, Element& element) {
    event.Accept(element);
}
```

#### Double Dispatch Using Tagged Unions (std::variant)

Since C++17 (or C++11 with a [single-header library](https://github.com/mpark/variant)), you can use a type-safe union called [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which can hold a fixed set of types in the same memory space, and dispatch between them.  A global method called [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) can be used to dispatch a callback based on the contained type of one or more variants. This happens to be really handy for double-dispatch.

First, use a variant to hold an event:

```cpp
struct MouseEvent { };
struct KeyEvent { };
using Event = std::variant<MouseEvent, KeyEvent>;
```

Then, a variant for each element, with methods to handle each event (use a base class to get rid of some boiler plate):

```cpp
struct BaseElement {
    template <typename TEvent>
    bool OnEvent(const TEvent&) { return false; }
};
struct ElementA : public BaseElement {
    using BaseElement::OnEvent;
    bool OnEvent(const MouseEvent&) { return true; }
};
using Element = std::variant<ElementA>;
```

Then use `std::visit` with a generic lambda to dispatch:

```cpp
void DispatchEvent(Event& event, Element& element) {
    std::visit([](auto&& el, auto&& ev) { return el.OnEvent(ev); }, element, event);
}
```

Ultimately, what this generates and optimizes to looks a bit like the event handler an old C GUI application:

```cpp
struct Event { int id; union { MouseEvent AsMouseEvent; KeyEvent AsKeyEvent; };  };
struct Element { int id; union { ElementA AsElementA; };  };
switch (event.id) {
    case MouseEvent:
        switch(element.id) { 
            case ElementA:
                return element.AsElementA.OnEvent(event.AsMouseEvent);
            /*...*/
        }
        break;
        /* ... */
}
```

#### Choosing

Neither method has a clear overall advantage performance-wise, so I recommend just using whichever one looks easier to use or maintain.

visitor pattern

- vtable size of visitors increases as types added
- can be used with C++98
- heterogeneous container must store dynamically allocated pointers to base type
- ... but no wasted object memory

std::variant

- amount of generated dispatch code increases as types added
- c++11 (via library, C++17 with std) or later
- can store heterogeneous members in contiguous memory
- ... but wasted memory if objects vary in size.

Demo of both: https://godbolt.org/z/MGp2No