# Is it ane analogue to <?> generics in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

For example i have templated structure

```
template <class T>
struct Event {
    T args;
    int32_t coordinate;
};
```

And for example i want to store
`Event<int32_t>` and `Event<std::vector<int32_t>>` in one vector. Is there any analog to generics from other languages like:
`std::vector<Event<?>>`?

**UPD** for all, who need to understand what i need to do: i have many events, which have different types of arguments. For example some events may have `int32_t` as `arg`, some `std::vector<int32_t>`, some `Event<int32_t>`, etc...

Comment: `std::vector<Event<std::any>>` with [any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: One way to do that would be to use a regular class (could be empty) as a base class for the class templates.

Comment: What would you do with it if it can have any type? "There is no useful universal class: a truly universal carries no semantics of its own." - Stroustrup. If your event class has an interface, store them using such interface.

Comment: you can also use variant : ```std::vector<Event<std::variant<int32_t , std::vector<int32_t>>>>```

Comment: BTW it is hard to understand what you want to do. Please edit your question

Comment: @user2407038, Please elaborate. `Event<int>` cannot be used where `Event<std::any>` is expected. I am not sure what you had in mind.

Comment: @user2407038 @AKL is there any variant for C++11? `std::any` and `std::variant` was added in C++17

Comment: your question is wage, do you want to have vector of events or event of vectors?

Comment: In the question for polymorphic object creator, my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116) has a `Table` that stores a vector of `object_t`, where they can are a homogenous polymorphic wrapper around non-homogenous objects.  Maybe something like that would work for you...?

Comment: Dear thematdev, there are number of solutions to deal with gathering different types under same banner like std::variant and std::tuple. as soon as you clarify what exactly you want to do, some one can give you an answer

Comment: @AKL I have many types of Events. `Event<Class1>`, `Event<Class2>`, etc. And in need to store them(for example in `std::vector`) to iterate over them or to sort them, etc.

Comment: The classical approach to this is inherit all `Event<T>` from a single non-template base class, then store `unique_ptr`s to that base in the vector.

Comment: @parktomatomi To cite the OP: _"i have many events"_ `std::variant` gets a bit tedious if there are many types to support. Though it could be placed in a single `typedef` or `using` clause to make maintencance easier.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's exactly the way to go. The alternative is the visitor pattern, which I find much more tedious.

Comment: @thematdev if `any` isn't available to you, your best solution will likely depend on exactly how you plan to use this type. `any` is a big hammer, and the most literal translation of `std::vector<Event<?>>` from other languages. Other options are `unique_ptr` or `variant` but it's hard to say which is best for you. If you really need the full power of `any`, but `any` isn't available in the version you're using, your best bet is to use a 3rd party lib which provides (boost) or to roll your own.

Comment: @parktomatomi The _Visitor Pattern_ is in deed the least way to go. I'd prefer _@Holy's_ solution over all the other proposals. This seems to be the most robust and least tedious in maintenance. Also you can define a homogeneous interface to handle processing the diverse event types.

Comment: This gets asked a _lot_: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495982/1863938

Comment: @user2407038 IMO, `std::any` is a good example of _type erasure_, but in practice is just inconvenient and error prone.

Comment: We get that you have different event types, but _many events_ isn't enough information. Do those events form an event queue in time order? Do you need random access or sequential access?

Answer (score 1):

Comment by @HolyBlackCat

> The classical approach to this is inherit all `Event<T>` from a single non-template base class, then store `unique_ptr`s to that base in the `vector`.

This is how you would do it.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

struct EventBase
{
   virtual ~EventBase() = default;
};

template <class T>
struct Event : public EventBase {
    T args;
    std::int32_t coordinate;
};

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<EventBase>> v;
   v.emplace_back(new Event<int>());
   v.emplace_back(new Event<double>());
}
```

Comment: What happens if `emplace_back` throws? That can only happen here on `std::bad_alloc` or `std::out_of_range`, which are rather unlikely, but this example doesn't generalise well, IMO.

Comment: Please explain how does one read back from the vector if he does not know the types

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, it didn't occur to me that that would be an issue for such a simple program. If you have some ideas, please suggest. I, and I'm sure the OP, will appreciate that.

Comment: @AKL, ideally, that wouldn't be necessary. If you need to get a derived class pointer, you'll have to preform `dynamic_cast` on the underlying pointer.

Comment: @RSahu - @MaximEgorushkin might be hinting that you should use `push_back(std::make_unique<Event<int>>())` to insert, so that if there's an exception (e.g. out of memory) while adding it to the container, the `unique_ptr` destructor will clean up the allocation

Comment: @RSahu, `dynamic_cast` is widely considered an anti-pattern because it requires the compiler to add RTTI information, requires run-time overhead to test, and design-wise forces you to update switch blocks everywhere you test. If you need type-specific functionality, use a virtual method to do functions without downcasting, or use the visitor pattern to separate your types and functions.